# How to replace more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

This is my code so far:

```
$("h1.intro:contains('|')").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('|','</span><br /><span>')) 
});
```

This works just once, but it has to work for all of those "|"...

any ideas?

Comment: Note that replace() is a javascript call and is not part of jQuery

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `/g` modifier:

```
$("h1.intro:contains('|')").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\|/g, '</span><br /><span>'));
});
```

**More Info:**

> The g modifier is used to perform a
>   global match (find all matches rather
>   than stopping after the first match).

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

Comment: the 'more correctly' works! I have to learn regular expressions, thx mates.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery 1.4, you can do this more nicely using the `.html(function))` signature:

```
$("h1.intro:contains('|')").each(function() {
    $(this).html(function(idx, oldContent) {
        return oldContent.replace(/\|/g, '</span><br /><span>');
    });
});
```

This means you don't have to create a second jQuery instance and should perform better.

Comment: +1: Useful; I hadn't known about this invocation of .html() before. Good call!

Answer (score 0):

Hi add a modifier to your regex by adding the "/g" after "|"

```
$("h1.intro:contains('|')").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("|/g",'</span><br /><span>')) 
});
```

Comment: You need to use a regex literal. JavaScript doesn't turn strings into regex literals on the fly.